# Changing inode behaviour

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, kernel, inode

I am trying to modify the ext3 file system. Basically I want to ensure that the inode for a file is saved in the same (or adjacent) block as the file that it stores metadata for. Hopefully this should help disk access performance

I grabbed the kernel source, compiled it, read a bunch about inodes and looked the inode.c file in the fs subdirectory. However, I am just not sure how I can ensure that any new file being created, and the inode for this file, can be saved in the same or adjacent blocks. Any help or pointers to further readings would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea.

I'm not deeply familiar with ext3, but I can give you some general pointers.

Currently ext3 stores inodes in predetermined places.  Each block group has its own inode table, an array of inodes.  So when you have an inode number (i.e., as the result of looking up a filename in a directory), you can find the corresponding inode on disk by using the inode number first to select the correct block group and then to index into that block group's inode table.

If you want to put the inodes next to the corresponding file data, you'll need a new scheme for finding an inode on disk.  If you're willing to dedicate a block for each inode, then  one possible scheme would be to allocate a new block every time you need an inode and then use the block number as the inode number.  This might have the benefit that for small files you could store the data in that same block.

To make something like this happen, creating a new file (i.e., allocating an inode) would have to work very differently than in the current ext3 file system.  Instead of using a bitmap to find an unused, pre-allocated and pre-initialized inode, you would have to allocate an empty block and initialize it yourself.  So, you'll probably want to look at how the file system allocates blocks when it's writing to a file, then mimic that for allocating an inode.

An alternative scheme would be to store the inode *inside* the directory.  So you save an I/O not because the inode is next to its data, but because when you lookup the filename you also read the inode.  This was done back in the 90s as an experiment in BSD's FFS file system, and was written up in an excellent [USENIX Paper](http://www.usenix.org/publications/library/proceedings/ana97/full_papers/ganger/ganger.pdf).  Those ideas never made it into FFS, or into any other main stream file system that I'm aware of, so it might be interesting to see how they work in ext3.

Regardless of whether you pursue one of these schemes or come up with something of your own, you'll also have to modify *mke2fs* to initialize the file system on disk in a way that your new file system variant will understand.

Good luck!  It sounds like a fun project.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos for getting into file system design!

First, a bit of engineering advice before you get too deep into hacking:  make a copy of the ext3 tree and rename the file system to something else.  I've found that when introducing experimental changes into a file system, you really don't want it to be used for your main system.  Your system should still boot even if you introduce a bug that randomly loses files (it will eventually happen).  You'll also need to branch the ext3 userspace tools to work with your new system.

Second, go get a copy of [Understanding the Linux Kernel, 3 ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005652) by Bovet and Cesati.  It presents an organized view of kernel subsystems, and I've found its explanations to be worthwhile.  It's written for an older kernel (2.6.*x* for some *x* < 15; I forget exactly), but it's still accurate in many places.  Read through its descriptions of file systems.  I believe it covers ext3.

Third, about your actual project, you aren't proposing a simple modification to ext3.  That file system has a pretty straightforward way of mapping an inode number to a disk block.  You'll need to find a new way of doing this mapping.  I would not anticipate any changes to the rest of ext3.  Solving this challenge may be one of the key design points of your architecture.  Note that keeping around a big array of inode -> disk block maps doesn't solve your problem:  it's probably no better than existing ext3.